# Parsing as string of data but leaving out quotes

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to use RegEx to run through a string of text but only return that parts that I need.  Let's say for example the string is as follows:

> 1234,Weapon Types,100,Handgun,"This is the text, "and", that is all."""

`\d*,Weapon Types,(\d*),(\w+),`  gets me most of the way, however it is the last part that I am having an issue with.  Is there a way for me to capture the rest of the string i.e.

> "This is the text, "and", that is all."""

without picking up the quotes?  I've tried negating them, however it just stops the string at the quote.

Please keep in mind that the text for this string is unknown so doing literal matches will not work.

Comment: I don't know for sure what you mean by "picking up the quotes".  You should show in your question the string that you want your program to extract.  I think you've instead shown some other string -- right?  Also, the input text looks very much like a line from a CSV file.  If that's what it is, why not use a dedicated CSV parser rather than a regular expression?

Comment: Almost CSV, except that there's nested commas.  See answer below.

Comment: Sorry about that, to be more specific, for the string:

1234,Weapon Types,100,Handgun,"This is the text, "and", that is all."""

using the RegEx above I want the result to be:

100,Handgun,This is the text, and , that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given us something very difficult to solve.  It's okay that you have nested commas inside your string.  Once we come across a double-quote, we can ignore everything until the end quote.  This would gooble up commas.

But how will your parser know that the next double-quote isn't ending the string.  How does it know that it a nested double-quote?

If I could slightly modify your input string to make it clear what is a nested quote, then parsing is easy...

```
        var txt = "1234,Weapon Types,100,Handgun,\"This is the text, &quot;and&quot;, that is all.\",other stuff";
        var m = Regex.Match(txt, @"^\d*,Weapon Types,(\d*),(\w+),""([^""]+)""");
        MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[3].Value);
```

But if your input string must have nested quotes like that, then we must come up with some other rule for detecting what is the real end of the string.  How about this?

```
        var txt = "1234,Weapon Types,100,Handgun,\"This is the text, \"and\", that is all.\",other stuff";
        var m = Regex.Match(txt, @"^\d*,Weapon Types,(\d*),(\w+),""(.+)"",");
        MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[3].Value);
```

The result is...

This is the text, "and", that is all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however that's not quite what I was looking for, and I apologize for not being more clear.  The end result that I seek is the string above without the quotes i.e.

1234,Weapon Types,100,Handgun,"This is the text, "and", that is all."""

Becomes

100,Handgun,This is the text, and , that is all.

So basically getting the whole string, minus the quotations.  I'm new to RegEx and so I may be asking it to do more than it is capable of, but I wanted to ask around and see if this was possible, and how it could be done.  

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I moved the parenthesis to be inside the quotes, so that the Regex captures just the inner string.